# Marshaling a method pointer with pointer argument in C#

Tags: c#, interop, cil

I need to marshal a method pointer with a pointer argument, like so in C:

```
void (*callback)(int *x);
```

How would I write that as struct field in C#?

**Note:** I don't mind having the CLR dereference the pointer for me.

Comment: That's a strange request, considering pointers are both unsafe and not CLS compliant. I wonder why you need to pass them around with delegates.

Comment: You could always pass a wrapper object; I.E. `Action<MyIntegerPointerWrapper> callback` and then use your wrapper.

Comment: It's for a specific unmanaged interop scenario; I need hand a off a function pointer that accepts struct pointer as an argument. Is there perhaps a way to do something like `Action<int>` and also have the marshaller dereference the pointer for me?

Comment: From reading online, it looks like I can declare my own delegate type like so: `delegate void RenderCallback([In][Out]int x);`, which should supposedly result in the marshaling that I'm after. I'll give it a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your method expects a callback accepting a pointer to any structure, you can pass a managed callback when specifying your P/Invoke DllImports like this:

```
private delegate void MyCallback(IntPtr par);

[DllImport("MyLibrary.dll")]
public static extern void SomeFunction(MyCallback callback);
```

You can then Marshal the `IntPtr` to an appropriate structure inside your actual callback method.

**[Edit]**

To pass an `int` parameter by reference, following delegate signature should work best:

```
private delegate void MyCallback(ref int par);
```

Comment: I considered doing that. Is there not a way to enforce the correct type (`int`) within C#'s type system, given my aforementioned scenario?

Comment: @Charles: have you tried passing it by reference: `delegate void MyCallback(ref int p)`?

Comment: Gah - dunno why I got so hungup on crap like InAttribute and OutAttribute. I'm willing to bet that'll do the trick. Feel free to create another answer stating that I should use `ref` and I'll select it. I'll update my question to fill the details that I've covered in the comments.

Comment: @Charles: great, but do make sure it's working before accepting this as answer.

Comment: @charles FYI: The InAttribute and OutAttributes don't impact the types used at the call site. So an [In()] T, [Out]T, and [In,Out] T will have the same "native signature". What [In] and [Out] do affect is the behavior of the marshaler. The [In] attribute tells the marshaler to copy the managed data into the native data before the call, and the [Out] attribute tells the marshaler to copy the native data back into managed memory after the call.